# How to run a external process on a PyQt5 OSX app, without crashing the app?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, external-process

I'm currently building an app that uses OCR to extract data from PDF files using PYQT5, and I need to use the terminal to convert the pdf into jpeg's before running the OCR; however, when I run this subprocess after compiling it crashes, **but it works perfectly if I don't compile the program.**

**It seems to me that the problem lies within the subprocess call. I've tried many different ways, but I don't know why my app keeps crashing after I compile and run the conversion.**

NOTE: For PDF to JPEG I'm using ImageMagick

**Currently using to compile:**

```
py2applet --make-setup main.py
python3 setup.py py2app
```

**Converter.py:**

```
from subprocess import call
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract 
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from ocrgui import Ui_MainWindow

class ImageConverter(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.show()
        self.sbmt_btn_convert.clicked.connect(self.convert_image)

    def convert_image(self): #Converts image into jpeg
        text = str(self.input_convert.text())
        output = str(self.output_convert.text())

        convert = 'converted.jpeg'
        call('convert -density 300 ' + text + ' ' + convert, shell=True)

        im = Image.open(convert)
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im, lang = 'eng')
        file = open(output,'w')
        file.write(text)
        file.close()

        call('rm converted.jpeg', shell=True)
        print('Succesfully created')
```

**Main.py:**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from calculator import CalculatorWindow

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

calculator = CalculatorWindow()

sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that problem in the next module:

pathPython\Lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageQt.py

Try to put # on the next lines:

```
...
try:
    from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage, qRgba, QPixmap
    from PyQt5.QtCore import QBuffer, QIODevice
    qt_version = '5'
except (ImportError, RuntimeError):
    print("except (ImportError, RuntimeError):!!!!!!!!!!!!")
    #try:
    #    from PyQt4.QtGui import QImage, qRgba, QPixmap
    #    from PyQt4.QtCore import QBuffer, QIODevice
    #    qt_version = '4'
    #except (ImportError, RuntimeError):
    #    try:
    #        from PySide.QtGui import QImage, qRgba, QPixmap
    #        from PySide.QtCore import QBuffer, QIODevice
    #        qt_version = 'side'
    #    except ImportError:
    #        qt_is_installed = False
...
```

Comment: This doesn't make a difference, and what should it fix btw?

Comment: Have you tried to remove these lines in ImageQt.py?
Remove these lines and re-assemble the file exe.

Comment: I did, still doesn't work. Not sure what the problem may be... Do you have any examples of how you would call an outside script from within your app?

Comment: The PySide.QtCore.QProcess class is used to start external programs and to communicate with them. https://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtCore/QProcess.html?highlight=qprocess

Comment: I've tried Qprocess as well, but it keeps crashing. Do you know any way to sort of check why is the app crashing after compiling it? Just like you would do when testing from terminal (Terminal usually tells you why, but after compiling nothing shows up) I'm starting to think is something else....

Comment: Just tested it and still the same crash. I think the problem lies between the Qprocess or subprocess whenever I call the outside program because I tried making an app with only built in functions and it works perfectly. I really don't know what to do haha....